# Spring 0-Legged authentication throws error "invalid_grant" with description "Bad credentials" when obtaining OAuth token with curl

Tags: java, curl, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to get [0-Legged](http://codehustler.org/blog/spring-security-tutorial-0-legged-oauth-1-0/) authentication to work with Spring Security and OAuth 2.0 for my RESTfull API. I am new to Spring Security curl and OAuth too, so I maybe doing something wrong, but I am trying to solve it for some time now.

When I execute curl command:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/rest/oauth/token" -d \ "username=admin&password=admin&client_id=test&client_secret=test&grant_type=password"
```

I get following exception:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}
```

After some debugging I found out that error is thrown in Spring Security class `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` in method `authenticate(Authentication authentication)` for user credentials  authentication (curl: admin, admin), client credentials (curl: test, test) are proccessed without exception.

Exception is thrown on this line:

```
user = retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
```

due to username string being set to NONE_PROVIDED on this line:

```
String username = (authentication.getPrincipal() == null) ? "NONE_PROVIDED" : authentication.getName();
```

After some more debuging I found out that in class Spring Security OAuth2 class `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter` in this method:

```
@Override
    protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {

        Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(tokenRequest.getRequestParameters());
        String username = parameters.get("username");
        String password = parameters.get("password");
        // Protect from downstream leaks of password
        parameters.remove("password");

        Authentication userAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        ((AbstractAuthenticationToken) userAuth).setDetails(parameters);
        try {
            userAuth = authenticationManager.authenticate(userAuth);
        }
        catch (AccountStatusException ase) {
            //covers expired, locked, disabled cases (mentioned in section 5.2, draft 31)
            throw new InvalidGrantException(ase.getMessage());
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            // If the username/password are wrong the spec says we should send 400/invlid grant
            throw new InvalidGrantException(e.getMessage());
        }
        if (userAuth == null || !userAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new InvalidGrantException("Could not authenticate user: " + username);
        }

        OAuth2Request storedOAuth2Request = getRequestFactory().createOAuth2Request(client, tokenRequest);      
        return new OAuth2Authentication(storedOAuth2Request, userAuth);
    }
```

username is set to null on next line due to key in `parameters` beeing " username" (note white space in front) instead of "username":

[image: screen shot from debugger]

```
String username = parameters.get("username");
```

So I tried to switch `username` and password parameters, and yes, which ever parameter is set first gets that white space in front for key value. I can work around it by adding another `username` parameter (or whichever is first), but that is not a solution.

Here is Spring OAuth configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"

    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

    <sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </sec:http>
    <sec:http pattern="/logout" create-session="never" 
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="ROLE_USER" method="GET"/>
        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
        <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </sec:http>
    <sec:http pattern="/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </sec:http>


    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager"> 
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
            <sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="jdbcDataSource" 
                users-by-username-query="SELECT username, passhash, enabled FROM  appuser WHERE USERNAME=?;"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.username, r.name FROM appuser u, roletype r, appuser_roletype a WHERE u.id = a.appuser_id AND r.id = a.roletype_id AND username =?;"/>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>


    <sec:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" />


    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials/>
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>


    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="86400" />
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore">
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="com.mytest.oauth.ClientDetailsServiceImplementation"/>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.mytest.oauth.LogoutImplementation">
        <property name="tokenstore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>
</beans>
```

How can I avoid that behaviour?

Comment: Usually spring's default token granters work fine. Could you please provide oauth server's configuration?

Comment: @nKognito sure, here it is

Comment: Are you sure that `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter` really has the issue with empty character before `username`? Source code looks fine: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/password/ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java#L58

Comment: And btw you try to POST to `/rest/oauth/token` while default configuration expects calls to `/oauth/token` and I can't see any additional configuration that overrides that behavior. Or it's just a app's web context?

Comment: @nKognito rest is actually place-holder for actual context (visible on screen-shot), but yes, it's a context, I've added debugger screen-shot along side curl command from terminal, that's exactly what I get, whether is it ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter or something else, I'm not sure

Comment: It's weird. I'd suggest to debug more deeply in order to discover where this empty char comes from